# GRE Multiple Choice Question - Select One or More Answer Choices

Tags: solution-verification, gre-exam

GRE Multiple Choice Question.

**Question:** If $a=3+b$, which of the following is true?

$\left (\mathrm{I}  \right ) a>b+2.5$

$\left (\mathrm{II}  \right )a<b+2.5$

$\left (\mathrm{III}  \right ) a>2+b$

Select One or More Answer Choices:

A. $\mathrm{I}$ only

B. $\mathrm{II}$ only

C. $\mathrm{III}$ only

D. $\mathrm{I}$ and $\mathrm{II}$ only

E. $\mathrm{I}$ and $\mathrm{III}$ only

Clearly $\mathrm{I}$ and $\mathrm{III}$ are true, so I think the answer is E. But GRE Practice Text's answer is A, C, and D and I am entirely not convinced they're correct.

Comment: I don't understand. GRE Text has three answers for this problem?

Comment: @Braindead Yes, the question says there can be one or more answer choices.

Comment: But those options are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's why I'm confused, but the text rarely has any wrong solutions.

Comment: ...Well, I don't really understand the book. But if $a = 3 + b$, then $a-b = 3$. So the question boils down to $I. 3> 2.5$, $II. 3 < 2.5$, and $III. 3 > 2$.

Comment: @user: it would have helped if you had cited the exact source of this problem (is it official or not?) so we could say the source is obviously unreliable or you're accidentally looking at the answer to a different problem....

Comment: @symplectomorphic the question is from Nova's GRE Math Prep, so yes it is official.

Comment: @user: uh... No it's not. "Official" means vetted and published by the people who make the test, ETS. You worked with a book from an independent company. Those books are filled with errors.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh, I see what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$A$ is wrong, because *both* I and III are true.

$B$ is wrong.

$C$ is wrong, because *both* I and III are true.

$D$ is wrong because while $I$ is true, $II$ is not.

$E$ is correct, since two and only two statements  are true: $I, III$.

Comment: Thanks. For a minute I was doubting my understanding of basic mathematics.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't you just hate it when purported solutions are incorrect?! It makes all of us start second-guessing ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is E. The provided answer is wrong.